# How do I make Eclipse automatically include jars I place in my WEB-INF/lib folder into my project?

Tags: java, gwt, jar, classpath

When I was doing JSP/Servlet programming, whenever I dropped 3rd party libraries into the WEB-INF/lib folder, they were automatically included in the project classpath. In GWT, this is not the case. Anyone know why? I loved how easy this was in JSP and I'd like these jars to be included automatically the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/) then my understanding is that a Google **Web Application Project** is just not the same animal than a **Dynamic Web Project** and thus behave differently. So if your project depends on libraries not provided by the GWT and App Engine SDKs, you'll need to put them in `war/WEB-INF/lib` and to add them explicitly to your Java build path.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Too bad though :)

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Galileo, right click the web project and select build path then select the Java EE Module Dependencies and add the jars.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plug-in technique that may help you if you want a directory where new jars are automatically updated in your build path, see this other post:

[Eclipse buildpath automatically taking all JARs of a internal directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483563/eclipse-buildpath-automatically-taking-all-jars-of-a-internal-directory/483641)

The reason it works like this for your JSP's is because that is how the Dynamic Web Project was made to behave.

"If you remove a library path entry but not the JAR file, the library entry will be re-added to the path automatically." from http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/ccwebprj.html

Comment: I might go with this route. I am still really confused as to why this works automatically with JSP/Servlets and not GWT. Maybe it has to do with how the JSP/Servlets plugin is written.

Answer (score 0):

You could adopt Maven and use the [Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/);  this plugin would update your classpath whenever you add a dependency.  There may be a similar plugin for [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/).

Comment: I'll take a look at that, but I'm still confused as to why this works with JSP/Servlets and not GWT, since the project structures are nearly the same which leads me to believe GWT is built on top of the Servlets framework.